# How to Get Custom Product Attribute In Sensei Product Recommendation

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, magento2.4, adobe-sensei, product-recommendation

How to get custom product attribute in **Adobe sensei product recommendation slider**.

It is a B2B Module [Sensei Magento2 Product Recommendation](https://devdocs.magento.com/recommendations/product-recs.html)

[image: Slider]

Kindly Share your Answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is above slider comes from the third party extension right?

Comment: Its a B2B module https://devdocs.magento.com/recommendations/product-recs.html

Comment: Then find out the phtml which is call for this one and you need to added code there same like name and price are show.

Comment: @chris Did you found any solution?

Comment: @RahulBarot I contact support team they said like.
there is no way to pass our custom attribute to their API.

Comment: @chris Thanks for information. Can you please have a look to my question if you have any idea on that https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/340095/magento-2-4-2-adobe-sensei-product-recommendations-missing-product-url-data

Answer (score 0):

I have the same need, soon you found how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/recommendations/customize.html):

> To make sure a custom product attribute is available when you render
> the recommendation unit on the page, set the Used in Product Listing
> property to Yes in the Product Attributes page in the Admin.
>
> When this property is set, the JSON payload includes an attributes
> object that contains an array of attribute codes and values. You can
> then apply custom storefront styling based on these attribute values,
> such as adding special visual treatments or badges as mentioned
> previously.

[image: Product Recommendations json response highlighting the custom attribute "manufacturer" in the "attributes" property.]

To show this value on your front-end, copy and paste the product recommendation template to `app/design/frontend/<THEME>/Magento_ProductRecommendationsLayout/web/template/recommendations.html` and inside the `each="products"` loop add (for example) `<span data-bind="text: attributes.manufacturer[0]"></span>` to show the value.